# Is there a way to render the name of a part on both sides of the page for the book documentclass?

Tags: books, parts

Is there a way to render the name of a part on both sides of a page for the book documentclass?

Essentially, rather than displaying the inserted page for the part title with a blank back, I would prefer that both the front and back of this page are identical, in that both display the part title.

I will ultimately be printing the entirety of the book tonight.
Of course, I can always feed the paper back into the printer to print the part name on the reverse side of the page, though I was hoping for a way to do this in LaTeX directly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Original Page]
[image: Identical Back Page]

Comment: please show us, at least, the line `\documentclas...{book}`

Comment: Do you want it as header or in the centre of the page?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \vfil\newpage\thispagestyle{plain} % or empty
    \null\vfil
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
     \vfil\newpage}
% next is for starred part if there is
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
    \vfil\newpage\thispagestyle{plain} % or empty
    \null\vfil
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
     \vfil\newpage}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
bla bla
\part{this is the first part}
some bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the cloned part page I would use `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: @Sigur, exactly - you don't want the header line to appear in the part title page.

Comment: @Sigur you're right